# Почему два блока сливаются в IE9?

Tags: css, internet-explorer

Привет
Так выглядят эти блоки в Мозилле:
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Так в IE9: 
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Код родителя синего блока:

```
.main {
        padding-bottom: 228px;
        position: relative;
        max-width: 1024px;
        min-width: 320px;
        margin: 20px auto 0 ;
    }
```

Код серого :

```
.recommend {
        max-width: 1024px;
        min-width: 969px;
        margin:  0 0 10px 0;
    }
```

Comment: max-width не любит IE. Если стоит max-width, то обязательно нужно указать width: 100%;

Comment: Буду иметь ввиду

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Попробуйте также указать `position` для серого? Скорее всего, IE9 не желает понимать, что серый должен стоять после голубого. Или, в начале, определите браузер, и напишите для IE другой стиль..

Comment: Супер! Правда пришлось подвинуть остальные блоки на то же расстояние и дать им position: relative, зато теперь все красиво. Спасибо еще раз

Comment: Рад был помочь)

Answer (score 0):

Можно между main и recommend добавить класс .clearfix

```
.clearfix{
  clear:both;
}
```